# How many numbers between $1$ and $200$ are multiples of $3$ or $5$ or $7$?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many numbers between $1$ and $200$ are multiples of $3$ or $5$ or $7$?

(a) $107$ (b) $108$ (c) $109$ (d) $110$ (e) $111$

I keep getting $108$ as my answer using PIE, and getting $66+40+28-13-5-9+1=108$, but the answer is (d) $110$, so I am really confused on where I am getting something wrong. Thank you

Comment: in order for us to point out where you went wrong please tell us how you got those value /used PIE.This helps us to tell where you went wrong.

Comment: between $1$ and $200$ *inclusive*?

Comment: $108$ is the correct answer by brute force.  Also, your calculations using PIE are correct.  It must be a typo an the answers sheet.

Comment: I agree with @saulspatz.  The answer is $108$ by the calculation you provide.  Easily confirmed directly.

Comment: Also agreeing with @saulspatz. Using a spreadsheet program such as Excel you can very quickly count the numbers by brute force.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, here are the 108 integers:     
3, 5, 6, 7, 9,10,12,14,15,18,
20,  21,  24,  25,  27,  28,  30,  33,  35,  36,
39,  40,  42,  45,  48,  49,  50,  51,  54,  55,
56,  57,  60,  63,  65,  66,  69,  70,  72 , 75,
77,  78,  80,  81,  84,  85,  87,  90,  91,  93,
95,  96,  98,  99, 100, 102, 105, 108, 110, 111,
112, 114, 115, 117, 119, 120, 123, 125, 126, 129,
130, 132, 133, 135, 138, 140, 141, 144, 145, 147,
150, 153, 154, 155, 156, 159, 160, 161, 162, 165,
168, 170, 171, 174, 175, 177, 180, 182, 183, 185,
186, 189, 190, 192, 195, 196, 198, 200

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: $107$ , is also possible. The question must specify if $1$ and $200$ are inclusive or exclusive.